# Accessing a file that is being written

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
You use the hadoop fs –put command to write a 300 MB file using and HDFS block size of 64 MB. Just after this command has finished writing 200 MB of this file, what would another user see when trying to access this file?

a.) They would see Hadoop throw an ConcurrentFileAccessException when they try to access this file.
b.) They would see the current state of the file, up to the last bit written by the command.
c.) They would see the current of the file through the last completed block.
d.) They would see no content until the whole file written and closed.
```

From what I understand about the `hadoop fs -put` command the answer is D, however some say it is C.

Could anyone provide a constructive explanation for either of the options?

Thanks xx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why the the file will not be accessible until the whole file is written and closed (option D) is because, in order to access a file, the request is first sent to the NameNode, to obtain metadata relating to the different blocks that compose the file. This metadata will be written by the NameNode only after it receives confirmation that all blocks of the file were written  successfully.

Therefore, even though the blocks are available, the user can't see the file until the metadata is updated, which is done after all blocks are written.

Answer (score 8):

As soon as a file is created, it is visible in the filesystem namespace. Any content written to the file is not guaranteed to be visible, however:

> Once more than a block's worth of data has been written, the first block will be visible to new readers. This is true of subsequent blocks, too: it is always the current block being written that is not visible to other readers. (From Hadoop Definitive Guide, Coherency Model).

So, I would go with Option C.

Also, take a look at this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377657/hadoop-hdfs-read-sequence-files-that-are-being-written).

Comment: Its true that the blocks are available at the block level, i.e you can access the individual block if you know which block to look for. However, if the metadata containing the mapping between File Name -> blocks is not available until all the blocks are written, the file itself will not be visible to users since all Filesystem requests are routed through the namenode

Comment: Here is what I have observed, while copying a big file to HDFS, the file name gets created as `[FILENAME]_COPYING_` and while the write is still going on, if you try to perform a read operation on the file (`[FILENAME]_COPYING`) you can still read the file until the last block written. I have tested this behavior in a Hadoop 2.4 cluster. So, from this behavior I guess that the NameNode updates the block map as soon as a block gets flushed (`hflush()`) and an ACK is sent back. Once the file write gets completed the file in HDFS gets renamed to `[FILENAME]`.

Comment: @AshrithM I've tried writing the 300MB file with the -PUT command and reading it with the -CAT command under the another user and got "File doesn't exist" message. What command (method) did you use to read the file that was being written?

Comment: @Dennis Ok, here is what I have done: First, kicked off a `put` as root user (the filename was `test.bat`), while the `put` is in progress the filename would be something like `test.bat._COPYING_` in HDFS. Then as cloudera user I read the file back using `hadoop fs -cat test.bat._COPYING_ | head`, which showed me the contents from the file. Finally, once the `put` is completed the file gets renamed to `test.bat` in HDFS. Attached is a screenshot for reference: [here](https://db.tt/67dtwus9)

Comment: @AshrithM did the same, but ran the "hadoop fs -cat test.bat" - without the ._copying_ suffix :) It is very confusing though :) Because basically if I told you to read a file named "TestFile" you wouldn't look for something called "TestFile._COPYING_", right? :) Besides that, thank you very much for your explanation and time! I believe it is now only to the people who made the test to know what the answer is :) I'll let you know if i score 100% :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems both D and C are true as detailed by [Chaos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269809/chaos) and [Ashrith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801327/ashrith), respectively.  I documented their results at https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/lestermartin/blog/2019/03/21/1172373509/are+partially-written+hdfs+files+accessible+not+exactly+but+much+more+yes+than+I+previously+thought when playing with a 7.5 GB file.

In a nutshell, yes, the exact file name is NOT present until completed... AND... yes, you can actually read the file up to the last block written iF you realize the filename is temporarily suffixed with `._COPYING_`.