# Hadoop dfs put create _COPYING_ staging file

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs, staging, copying

I am trying put a big file to hdfs and seeing a staging file with '_COPYING_' suffix , created . My question is is this staging file can be available to use as soon as any block is copied to HDFS ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the staging file is available as soon as a block is copied by DataNode. See the discussion (comments) in this question: [Accessing a file that is being written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634057/accessing-a-file-that-is-being-written/26638408#26638408).