# Python: how to know if file is finished uploading into hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, file-upload, hdfs

So I have 2 scripts:
script1 for upload file to hdfs
script2 will access the folder and read the files every n seconds

my upload script is like this

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('hadoop', 'password')
client_hdfs = InsecureClient('http://hadoop.domain.com:50070', user='hadoop', session=session)
client_hdfs.upload(hdfsPath,filePath,overwrite=True)
```

when I read https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/lestermartin/blog/2019/03/21/1172373509/are+partially-written+hdfs+files+accessible+not+exactly+but+much+more+yes+than+I+previously+thought
or in stackoverflow [Accessing a file that is being written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634057/accessing-a-file-that-is-being-written).

It seems when I upload using hadoop dfs -put command (or -copyFromLocal or -cp) it will create [filename].*COPYING* if the file is not finished yet. But in the python script it seems it will create the file with the same name but the size will increasing overtime until it completed (and we can download it before it complete and get corrupted file).

I want to ask if there is a way to upload the file using python so that we knows that the file is finished uploading or not.

Actually I has another work-around to upload them into temporary folder and move them to the correct folder after all is finished (I am still trying to do this), but if there is another idea for this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same strategy as hDFS

1. create [filename].COPYING
2. When data is uploaded rename to [filename]

I feel like you suggested the same thing with a temp file, instead of a name change, but it amounts to the same idea.  Just so you know renaming a file is extremely cheap and fast so by all means this is a good strategy.

Comment: Doesn't the same problem exist? How would you know the copying file is completely uploaded? I feel like you need to verify the Content Length before renaming

Comment: I did make two assumption that may not be true. 1 ) the steps could be run sequentially. (Single threaded) [upload & then rename].  2) the issue was external to the program not internally to python.  Externally to the program you know that  you are good when ".COPYING" has be removed.  Renames don't require re-writing of the file which is why HDFS uses this strategy.

Comment: thanks,I think I like your suggestion. 
by that way, I dont need to change the other program that read the file (it will always ignore _COPYING_ files because hdfs command by default use that). the one thaat I found only python using hdfscli lib, I dont know about another programming language lib, it can has similar problem, as long as I keep everything works as same as how hdfs command should be fine

Comment: If you have it enable you could consider using webHDFS.  I don't remember the limitations on file size though. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html